Terminal wealth in multiperiod asset pricing?
I am studying an asset pricing problem and I am having a tough time using finite horizon because I cannot properly define the terminal wealth.
I consider agents with exponential utility, who can consume only at the last period. So, the objective is to maximize terminal wealth at time T. I see how wealth at time n<T will be the returns on the portfolio held plus the price at n of that portfolio, and that price depends on the demand at time n. How to define the price of the final portfolio held? Since the model stops at T we cannot know what the future demand will be or know what the final price is, unless we add more periods to model.
Thank you !
